# How do i collapse panels so that the panels below it take their space?

Tags: c#, panels

im not the strongest visual studio v# developer so please bear with me.

I am trying to have multiple panels on a page, one below the other, with what will amount to a line of text in each one.

Sometimes, I do not want to show some of these panels.  When I don't want to show a panel, I want the panels below it to 'move up' and take its spot... essentially, when panels aren't visible, I don't want a ton of blank space filling their location.

How the heck can I do this?  ive tried a bunch of things but im at a loss..

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please specify if WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or whatever tech are you using

Comment: sorry... im using a windows form

Comment: guys, what has been marked here as an ANSWER is not what I am looking for.  An accoridian panel wont do it.  I need lines of text to show or not show based on code-behind, and the ones that don't show to take up no space on the page.  The accordion panel seems to let users expand or contract a panel, and that's NOT what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/40B89FC7-80FA-4E95-B707-506084F51D6B

Or that se System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer

inside the SplitContainer panel you can use a FlowLayoutPanel or a custom toolbox

Comment: thanks marco.  I don't think that's going to cut it for me tho.  I don't really want a panel to be collapsible by the user.  Basically, I want some lines of text (I had thought to put each in its own panel), and then have the hidden or shown based on code-behind... I cant have the user clicking them to see them or not.. the visibility of them must happen behind the scenes